# Searching for a program to test bug finding

Tags: learning, training

I've been searching the internet for the last two hours and wasn't able to grasp any useful information.

I'd be looking for a program where trainees are able to search for bugs in e.g. a client or GUI. In other words a buggy software where people are able to learn finding errors and bugs.

Not sure it even exists but it would help to differentiate certain people at job interviews which don't fit to be e.g. test engineers.

Hope I was able to made myself clear. Thanks in advance for all the useful information.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such application, but it could be a pretty interesting endeavor.  Maybe that's a project you should kick off.  :)

Comment: This may be context dependent, but I'm not sure this is a good idea.  A program doesn't exist in a vacuum, you also need things like spec documents, or user stories, or whatever you want to call them.  And for anything of a reasonable level of complexity, you need tools to test programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that anyone releases intentionally buggy software (with easy-to-find bugs), with possible exception of first version of any MicroSoft software :-), or some obscure open-source project which no-one uses anymore (and bugs will be the reason).

So if you want a system with known bugs, best way IMHO would be to preserve a old buggy version of your own software, deploy it on a test server, and let your candidates poke around.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Already thought about it and it makes probably the most common sense.

Answer (score 1):

At my employer, we write our own code fragments to use in test engineer interviews.  It isn't hard to use your bug tracking system and your version control system to identify buggy code fragments.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Already thought about it and it makes probably the most common sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a game with some bugs:

http://angryweasel.com/blog/?p=340